# CSS Box Shadow Like This Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the current CSS box shadow code which I'm trying to imitate the effects of this website http://danielladraper.com/

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 22px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 22px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 22px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GCwBT/

If you scroll down to the bottom of that site and hover over one of their products, you'll see that a box shadow appears over one of the products. However when I apply this to my div's, which are floated next to each other, only part of the the box shadow is visible, the other portion seems to get blocked.

I have no idea why this is happening, even though both of our divs appear to be floating left.

Anyone able to tell me what sort of js/css combo that site is using to achieve that CSS shadow effect?

Thanks

Comment: you may want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/GCwBT/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to consider that box-shadow only appears when the user hovers the box.

In your jsfiddle, all the boxes have shadow. You have to change it to:

```
.boxes {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

.boxes:hover {
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 22px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 22px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 22px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);   
  z-index: 999;
}
```

The z-index property brings the box to front. And it works with position:relative (or any others, you need position:relative)

Regards.

Comment: Oh yea, I forgot about the z-index CSS property, that's what makes their div pop out :)

Comment: Yes, but is important to add the z-index only on hover, because if you add the z-index in .boxes, there is no effect!

Comment: Yep, any idea what sort of transition their using?

Comment: Sure, the transition is: box-shadow 0.2s linear,background-color 0.2s linear

Answer (score 1):

Your shadow must be blocking because you are not using z-index, along with this css you also need to specify the z-index when you hover.

`.boxes:hover{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 22px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 22px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 22px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index:10;
}`
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sunitj/GCwBT/2/)

P.S. For your case position:relative property is required to bring z-index in effect